# How to deploy a Office 2010 add-in with Visual Studio 2010 setup & deployment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation, ms-office

We have an error during the installation after running our installation:

> Component Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64) has failed to install with the following error message:
>
> "A failure occurred attempting to install the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)."
>
> The following components failed to install:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)
>
> See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD831C.tmp\install.log' for more information.

The log file return:

> Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD831C.tmp\VSTOR40\vstor40_x64.exe
>
> WinVerifyTrust returned -2146869232
>
> File not trusted
>
> Installing using command 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD831C.tmp\VSTOR40\vstor40_x64.exe' and parameters ' /q:a /c:"install /q /l"'
>
> Process exited with code 536870913
>
> Status of package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'

How proceed to install successfully our Office 2010 add-in?

**UPDATE**: Ok for your answers but the goal is to deploy the app with the installer I test. So the end-user will have the same error as me. The goal is to avoid this error in the setup configuration in Visual Studio 2010. How can I add VSTO 4 runtime in the installer and obtain no error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be Microsoft bug. They have released un-signed version of the installer that throws error:
WinVerifyTrust returned -2146762496. File not signed.

I'm not sure if it will help in your case. The fix for me was to download new version from [Microsoft downloads website](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=06c32242-2289-4471-93aa-ce96aa5cbc36) .
The full description of the bug is available here:
[VSTO Runtime installation error](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/555644/vsto-runtime-installation-error-file-changed-since-published?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Are you you installing with elevated privalages? That may be why WinVerifyTrust is not trusting vstor40_x64.exe.

Second thing to check is if you are installing in order - first the .NET run time (3.51 or 4.0, depending on your add-in), then vstor40_x86.exe or vstor40_x64.exe (depending on client machine x86 or x64), then your solution.

If it's not as simple as this, check out [Troubleshooting Office Solution Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608594.aspx) and/or [Troubleshooting ClickOnce Deployments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb94w1t5.aspx) (if you're using ClickOnce).

Comment: The setup is running with admin right. The .NET run time are version 4.0 and was installed correctly with the setup.